bondingCurve Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated
I tried replacing "REDACTED" with the code below. I'm not sure if it's a good fix, but the code fails to create a new launch. Could you please provide some assistance?
git code  : https://github.com/bilix-software/pump-fun-token-launcher/blob/77bbc0fe2ae05896a23809f58cb43e112e9bdb4c/src/launch.ts#L60
    //const bondingCurve = new PublicKey("REDACTED")
    const TRADE_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA');
    const BONDING_ADDR = new Uint8Array([98, 111, 110, 100, 105, 110, 103, 45, 99, 117, 114, 118, 101]);
    const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([BONDING_ADDR, mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], TRADE_PROGRAM_ID);
    //const associatedBondingCurve = new PublicKey("REDACTED")
    const [associatedBondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([bondingCurve.toBuffer(), TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);

    //const metadata = new PublicKey("REDACTED")
    const META_ADDR = new Uint8Array([109, 101, 116, 97, 100, 97, 116, 97]);
    const METAPLEX_TOKEN_META = new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s');
    const [metadata] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([META_ADDR, METAPLEX_TOKEN_META.toBuffer(), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], METAPLEX_TOKEN_META);

==================================================
Below is the error :
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x7d6
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (E:\dev\nodejs\dessertcorenode\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8052:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (E:\dev\nodejs\dessertcorenode\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8017:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (E:\dev\nodejs\dessertcorenode\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8008:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (E:\dev\nodejs\dessertcorenode\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2180:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Create',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint2',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2780 of 188555 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: bonding_curve. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',
    'Program log: Left:',
    'Program log: 7Mu152gzqNCP4JuttXmsoN4J1EvsBsAWpKmHePUwRRgQ',
    'Program log: Right:',
    'Program log: 2w1JdkzwNnMug6aPV7UqhFQJ8mPxvX3fqbXqT9EihrjL',
    'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P consumed 21828 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P failed: custom program error: 0x7d6'
  ]
}


The complete code is here :
https://github.com/bilix-software/pump-fun-token-launcher/blob/77bbc0fe2ae05896a23809f58cb43e112e9bdb4c/src/launch.ts#L60
I have replaced the constants, watching solscan transaction "created token" via pump.fun website:
const SYSTEM_PROGRAM = SystemProgram.programId;
const RENT = SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY;

const GLOBAL = new PublicKey("4wTV1YmiEkRvAtNtsSGPtUrqRYQMe5SKy2uB4Jjaxnjf");
const PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT = new PublicKey("Ce6TQqeHC9p8KetsN6JsjHK7UTZk7nasjjnr7XxXp9F1")
const MPL_TOKEN_METADATA = new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");
const MINT_AUTHORITY = new PublicKey("TSLvdd1pWpHVjahSpsvCXUbgwsL3JAcvokwaKt1eokM");
const COMPUTE_BUDGET_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111");

const PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM = new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P");
const BONDING_ADDR = new Uint8Array([98, 111, 110, 100, 105, 110, 103, 45, 99, 117, 114, 118, 101]);
const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([BONDING_ADDR, mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT);

const [associatedBondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([bondingCurve.toBuffer(), PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT.toBuffer(), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID);

const META_ADDR = new Uint8Array([109, 101, 116, 97, 100, 97, 116, 97]);
const METAPLEX_TOKEN_META = new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s');
const [metadata] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([META_ADDR, METAPLEX_TOKEN_META.toBuffer(), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], METAPLEX_TOKEN_META);

const txBuilder = new web3.Transaction();

const computeBudgetInstruction = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [], programId: COMPUTE_BUDGET_PROGRAM_ID,
    data: Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(Uint8Array.of(3)), bufferFromUInt64(100000)])
});

txBuilder.add(computeBudgetInstruction);

const keys = [
    { pubkey: mint.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }, // Mint account
    { pubkey: MINT_AUTHORITY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Mint authority
    { pubkey: bondingCurve, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }, // Bonding curve PDA
    { pubkey: associatedBondingCurve, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }, // Associated bonding curve PDA
    { pubkey: GLOBAL, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Global config
    { pubkey: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Metadata program ID
    { pubkey: metadata, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }, // Metadata PDA
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }, // Owner account
    { pubkey: SYSTEM_PROGRAM, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // System program
    { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Token program
    { pubkey: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Associated token account program
    { pubkey: RENT, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Rent sysvar
    { pubkey: PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }, // Pump fun account
    { pubkey: PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM, isSigner: false, isWritable: false } // Pump fun program ID
];



The IDL for program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P is published and I'm guessing it's pump.fun
I'm assuming error you are encountering is telling you that the coin no longer exists on pump.fun because the $69k market cap has been reached and the liquidity has been moved to Raydium and burned.

Hello Jimii, you are correct. I'm trying to launch a new token through the code, but I haven't been successful.

const PUMP_FUN_PROGRAM = new PublicKey("6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P");
const BONDING_ADDR = new Uint8Array([98, 111, 110, 100, 105, 110, 103, 45, 99, 117, 114, 118, 101]);
const [bondingCurve] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([BONDING_ADDR, mint.publicKey.toBuffer()], PUMP_FUN_ACCOUNT);

same error : 'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: bonding_curve. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',

It's really hard to know which seeds constraint was violated without looking at their code. Might be an address, mutable, init amount others. Also, why not do it through their platform?

updated coded : The complete code is here : https://github.com/bilix-software/pump-fun-token-launcher/blob/77bbc0fe2ae05896a23809f58cb43e112e9bdb4c/src/launch.ts#L60
I have replaced the constants, watching solscan transaction "created token" via pump.fun website:

This repo should answer all your questions:
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk/blob/main/src/pumpfun.ts#L343
const PROGRAM_ID = "6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P";
export const BONDING_CURVE_SEED = "bonding-curve";

getBondingCurvePDA(mint: PublicKey) {
    return PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(BONDING_CURVE_SEED), mint.toBuffer()],
      this.program.programId
    )[0];
  }

async getBondingCurveAccount(
    mint: PublicKey,
    commitment: Commitment = DEFAULT_COMMITMENT
  ) {
    const tokenAccount = await this.connection.getAccountInfo(
      this.getBondingCurvePDA(mint),
      commitment
    );
    if (!tokenAccount) {
      return null;
    }
    return BondingCurveAccount.fromBuffer(tokenAccount!.data);
  }

IDL Updated to Anchor 0.30.X
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk/blob/main/src/IDL/pump-fun.json
LMK if you have questions
